# react getting an error when posting to MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, reactjs

I'm trying to POST a record to my MS SQL database and I'm getting an Internal Server Error status of 500 which is the response programmed in the api:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Save Budget to MSSQL database
    Budgets.create({
        clientid: req.body.clientid,
        catitem: req.body.catitem,
        subcatitem: req.body.subcatitem,
        startDate: req.body.startDate,
        endDate: req.body.endDate,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        frequency: req.body.frequency,
        cost: req.body.cost
    }).then(budget => {
        // Send created budget to budget
        res.send(budget);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    })
};
```

Here is the code for posting the record from the client:

```
export const createBudget = (budgetData = {
    clientid: null,
    catitem: '',
    subcatitem: '',
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    quantity: '',
    frquency: '',
    cost: ''
}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const budget = {
            clientid: budgetData.clientid,
            catitem: budgetData.catitem,
            subcatitem: budgetData.subcatitem,
            startDate: budgetData.startDate,
            endDate: budgetData.endDate,
            quantity: budgetData.quantity,
            frequency: budgetData.frequency,
            cost: budgetData.cost
        };

        return axios.post('budgets/create', budget).then(result => {
            dispatch(_createBudget(result.data));
        });
    };
};
```

Initially this worked with with just four columns in the table (clientid, catitem, subcatitem, and cost) but I had to add extra columns and now it dosen't work. When I click the link shown in Developer Tools I get a page that states: "Cannot GET /api/budgets/create" yet the route defined in the api is: "app.post('/api/budgets/create', budgets.create);"

Is the "Cannot GET /api/budgets/create" the typical response for a failure to a post or is there something else going on? And how do I determine what the root cause is for the failure? Also I can INSERT a record into the table using Azure Data Studio with a SQL statement (developing on a Mac).

Answer (score 0):

So after further analysis I discovered that I had to manually add the fields createdAt and updatedAt (required by Axios) to the database table then restart the Docker MS Sql service. Everything now works. What tipped me off to this solution was noticing and examining the initial get of the Budgets table and that's what was failing and therefor the failing of the POST request.